# Sync kill a non-child process in node

Tags: node.js

I would like to use node to synchronously close another process. I do know the process ID. I need to be sure this process has exited before another process starts.

Ideally it would look like:

```
await process.kill(pid);
```

where `await` actually waits for the process to close. However, the docs tell me that process.kill only sends an exit signal. It does not seem to wait for a return signal or some indication that the process is no longer running.

I see `process.exit()` is not an option here because it doesn't take a process ID. In fact it seems somehow related to child processes - but I do find the docs tricky to understand. The process I want to kill is not a child process.

Answer (score -1):

You can see here node js [process kill](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_kill_pid_signal)

```
process.on('SIGINT', () => {
     //Do what is next when process got killed
    });


process.kill(pid, 'SIGINT');
```

The process.kill() method sends the signal to the process identified by pid.

Signal names are strings such as 'SIGINT' or 'SIGHUP'